# Parsing Custom JSON Response with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is my first attempt at trying to parse a json response with json.net and I am totally lost.  I have included a section of the parsed json below.  What I would like to do do is loop through the backlinks array.  I have tried implementing various samples from the newtonsoft documentation, but they don't seem to work and I think it is because my json doesn't match their samples and I don't have knowledge to make the necessary corrections.  If someone could provide some C# code to get me started I would really appreciate it.

Thanks, 
Chaos

```
{
"accounts": [
    {
        "10555": {
            "sites": [
                {
                    "12222": {
                        "pages_indexed_in_bing": {},
                        "download_time": null,
                        "backlinks": [
                            {
                                "anchor_text": "websites for insurance agents",
                                "source_url": "http://win-winbusinesses.com/insurance/how-to-building-an-effective-insurance-website/",
                                "found_on": "2015-07-15",
                                "page_authority": null,
                                "link_strength": 3,
                                "domain": "win-winbusinesses.com",
                                "domain_authority": 17
                            },
```

Comment: Use a tool like http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have tried a couple of different class generators, but the json response that I working with caused errors with all of them, which is why I am now trying to query the response directly.

Comment: You should post a complete response here.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ is another good alternative

Comment: the `json` seems invalid

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  I ran the JSON response through jsonlint and it validated the response.  Unfortunately, the entire response is too large for me to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as stated before, the JSON you've provided is invalid.
I assume it should look like this:

```
{
"accounts": [
    {
        "10555": {
            "sites": [
                {
                    "12222": {
                        "pages_indexed_in_bing": {

                        },
                        "download_time": null,
                        "backlinks": [
                            {
                                "anchor_text": "websites for insurance agents",
                                "source_url": "http://win-winbusinesses.com/insurance/how-to-building-an-effective-insurance-website/",
                                "found_on": "2015-07-15",
                                "page_authority": null,
                                "link_strength": 3,
                                "domain": "win-winbusinesses.com",
                                "domain_authority": 17
                            }
                        ]

                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

And according to this JSON, you're classes should look like this if you want newtonsoft to succeed parsing:

```
public class PagesIndexedInBing
{
}

public class Backlink
{
    public string anchor_text { get; set; }
    public string source_url { get; set; }
    public string found_on { get; set; }
    public object page_authority { get; set; }
    public int link_strength { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public int domain_authority { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__12222
{
    public PagesIndexedInBing pages_indexed_in_bing { get; set; }
    public object download_time { get; set; }
    public List<Backlink> backlinks { get; set; }
}

public class Site
{
    public __invalid_type__12222 __invalid_name__12222 { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__10555
{
    public List<Site> sites { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public __invalid_type__10555 __invalid_name__10555 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Account> accounts { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there might be problems since you using class/var names that are only numerical, so you probably should check this as well.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the issue the class/var names I tried that class generator as well.  This is way I am trying to query the json without serializing it.

Comment: Felix or Amit, could either of you give more information on how the json is invalid?  I would like to bring these concerns to the API vendor.  Is there a specification that I could to provide documentation of the validation errors?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: From what I see there are two problems:
1. Some of the brackets, that are part of the JSON formatת were missing/misplaced. Probably because it's just a part of the response and not all of it.
2. JSON format describes the data and also the class structure, including it's name. Therefore response that, according to JSON format, implies there's a class which name is "12222" is invalid, because class name has to start with a letter.

Comment: Thanks, Felix.  That is a big help.

Comment: You're welcome! If it was helpful please upvote the answer and mark the question as answered. Thanks